# Cross thread exception error

Tags: c#

I am getting the error cross thread exception while debugging one application , but not at run time . If I added the code 
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
its working fine . Do I need to change the code like this ?so that in future this error wont happen at run time. Is it a right approach?

Comment: Are you accessing controls from secondary threads?

Comment: "while debugging" - do you have lots of extra debug or trace code that's only active in debug mode that might be causing this?

Comment: Use Invoke, dont use CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls. See this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's the wrong approach of course... setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false` may lead to problems

Comment: yes , i am accessing a drop down value from secondary threads.